# HQL to check if all element from a list is exist in a table

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a Entity class named `Role.java` and a `Role_tbl` table in database. In my code I have an `ArrayList` of `Role` - `roleList` . I just want to check if all role from the `roleList` exist in the `Role_tbl`.

So first of all I have fetch all data from `Role_tbl` put them in a new `ArrayList` of `Role` - `roleListfromDB`. After that using a for each loop I have done the checking -

```
for(Role each : roleList){
   if(!roleListFromDB.contains(each)){
     flag = false; 
     break;
   }
}
```

But I think it is not efficient enough. I know there is  a `exist` clause in hql. I can use it for checking a single object. But can I use it to check whether the whole `roleList` exist in DB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So first of all I have fetch all data from Role_tbl

No you don't.
Just query the table for matching entities and if the returned list is same size, they are all there.

If you don't need to know which entities are missing/present ... you could just do a count ( @JBNizet )